# Rails 5 cancancan defining ability with multiple condition and checking ability with single condition doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

Given the following scenario

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrolments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :teams, through: :enrolments
end
```

team.rb

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :coaches, class_name: "User", join_table: "teams_coaches"
end
```

ability.rb

```
if user.canrole == "coach"
  can :read, User, canrole: "player", teams: { coaches: { id: user.id } }
end
```

I have differentiated the roles of user by a column in user table.
I need the coach to only see the players for the team which he is coaching.
The given rule is successfully working while I use the accessible_by method on index method
`User.accessible_by(current_ability)`
it gives me only those players which coach has access to.

but the following is not working properly.
`can?(:index, User.new(canrole: 'player'))`
this block of code is used by me to display a navigation menu item called 'players' for a coach user.

Expected Behaviour

The `can?(:index, User.new(canrole: 'player'))` should return true, as the coach has access to a few players.

Actual Behaviour

The `can?(:index, User.new(canrole: 'player'))` is returning false

---

This is somewhat similar to
https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/docs/Checking-Abilities.md#checking-with-class

where we define the ability rule with a hash, but we check the rule without providing the condition and still we get true in return, because the user has access to at least one project

```
can :read, Project, :priority => 3
can? :read, Project # returns true
```

so the same even though we have defined the ability rule with multiple conditions and we are checking the rule with only one condition, it should return true, because one of the conditions of rule is true while checking with instance.

---

The summary is, the rule is defined with hash of conditions where has contains multiple conditions, but while I check I am checking with only one attribute for using it to check whether I should display 'players' in the navigation menu or not.
So seems like if a rule is defined with multiple conditions we can not just check with only one condition.

Answer (score 0):

The action `can? :index` can only be performed on the Class level and is usually used as `User.accessible_by(current_ability)` which checks the action `:index` by default.

If you want to know "is there at least one player I can coach?" you need to do

```
User.accessible_by(current_ability).any?
```

Comment: actually, the code `User.accessible_by(Ability.new(current_user)).any?` where `current_user` is coach will return false in case of no players, which can happen when the coach is not assigned to any team or the team have no players and I still need to display a "players" menu item in the navigation menu even if a coach has no players. For which I am trying to use `can?(:index, User.new(canrole: 'player'))` because other methods don't seem to fit fot this. Displaying players based on role are working properly, its just I need to decide whether a user(coach) can see the "players" menu item or not

Comment: Your use case is different then. You are describing two different permissions. With one permission you define if the coach is able to see other players and which ones. With the other permission you define whether the coach can see a menu for players at all. When can a coach see the Players menu? What are the conditions? Because having at least a player doesn't seem the correct one.